# Standardising Bivariate Normal

Tags: probability

[image]

I don't understand why $\sigma_{Z_1}=\sigma_{Z_2}=1$ and $\mu_{Z_1}=\mu_{Z_2}=0$. 
I would understand if:

$X_1$~$N(\mu_{x_1},\sigma_{x_1}^2)$ and  $X_2$~$N(\mu_{x_2},\sigma_{x_2}^2)$ but this is not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The means are $0$ because you first subtract $\mu_X$ from $X$, and expectation is linear. Similarly, the variance is $1$ because you are dividing by $\sigma_X$ and the original variance of $X$ is $\sigma_X^2$ (which is unchanged if you subtract the mean $\mu_X$ from $X$) and $var(cX) = c^2 var(X)$ for a constant $c$.

In other words, you do have $X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$ by assumption.